# pandas drop_duplicates() "keep" parameter gives very different answers - how does it work?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV dataset of olympic athletes participated in games.

the features are: id,Name,Sex,Age,Games,Year,Sport

I need to find:

> What was the percentage of male basketball players among all the male
> participants of the 2012 Olympics? Round the answer to the first
> decimal.

One athlete can compete in various formats, so there are duplicates.

I query with this code without "keep" parameter:

```
    males_2012 = data[   (data['Sex']=='M') & (data['Year']==2012)].drop_duplicates(subset=['ID',],inplace=False)
    len(males_2012) # gives 5863
```

However it gives me much smaller dataset if I query with "keep=False":

```
males_2012 = data[   (data['Sex']=='M') & (data['Year']==2012) ].drop_duplicates(subset=['ID',], 
keep=False,inplace=False)
    len(males_2012) # 5020
```

The official drop duplicates explanation of parameter "keep":

[drop_duplicates() official docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

> keep : {‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’ first : Drop
>
> duplicates except for the first occurrence. last : Drop duplicates
>
> except for the last occurrence. False : Drop all duplicates.

I found the right answer, however I still can't see why it gives me very different answer depending on 'keep=False' parameter.

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What piece is confusing you? If you don't pass in the parameter, it defaults to keep the first record. If you pass in `False`, it doesn't keep any of the records. The difference in count should be the difference between those two numbers. Is that not the case?

Comment: `keep=False` drop **all** duplicates. For example, if you have two rows with same values, `keep=False` gets rid of both, while the other two options keeps one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

keep defines which duplicate value you want to keep.

1) First specifies to keep the first duplicate value and drop the rest.

2) Last specifies to keep the last duplicate value and drop the rest.

3) False specifies to drop all duplicates.

Consider the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1]})

print(df.drop_duplicates(keep='first'))
print(df.drop_duplicates(keep='last'))
print(df.drop_duplicates(keep=False))
```

The outputs are:

```
   A
0  1
   A
3  1
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
```

We can see in the first df, the element kept was at index 0, so it was the first element. The second df has the index of 3 so it was the last element. The last df has no data since the entire column was a duplicate so all was dropped.

Comment: ohh, so if i have 3 IDs and keep = false, it will drop ALL 3 and leave none in the dataset.. ?

Comment: Reproduce my dataset and just add columns `B` and `C` with duplicate values and give it a try :P